# Aggregate a dataframe column based on a hierarichal condition from another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have an interesting problem and thought I will share it here for everyone. Let's assume we have a pandas DataFrame like this (dummy data):

| Category | Samples |
| --- | --- |
| A,B,123 | 6 |
| A,B,456 | 3 |
| A,B,789 | 1 |
| X,Y,123 | 18 |
| X,Y,456 | 7 |
| X,Y,789 | 2 |
| P,Q,123 | 1 |
| P,Q,456 | 2 |
| P,Q,789 | 2 |
| L,M,123 | 1 |
| L,M,456 | 3 |
| S,T,123 | 5 |
| S,T,456 | 5 |
| S,T,789 | 3 |

The value in category are basically hierarchal in nature. Think of A as country, B as state, and 123 as zip-code. What I want is to greedily match for each category which has less than 5 samples and merge it with the nearest one. The final example DataFrame should be like:

| Category | Samples |
| --- | --- |
| A,B,123 | 10 |
| X,Y,123 | 18 |
| X,Y,456 | 9 |
| P,Q,456 | 5 |
| L,M,456 | 4 |
| S,T,123 | 8 |
| S,T,456 | 5 |

These are the possible rules I see that will be needed:

Case A,B : Sub-categories 456, 789 have less than 5 categories so we merge it but then the merged one will also have 4 which is less than 5 so it gets further merged with 123 and thus finally we get A,B,123 with 10.

Case X,Y : Subcategory 789 is the only one with less than 5 so it will merge with the category 456 (the one closest to 5 samples) to become X,Y,456 as 9 where X,Y,123 always had more than 5 so it remains as is.

Case P,Q : Here all the sub-categories have less then 5 but the idea is to merge it one at a time and it has nothing to do with the sequence. 123 here is having one sample, so it will merge with 789 to form a sample size of 3 which is still less than 5 so it will merge with 456 to form P,Q,456 with sample size of 5 but it can also be P,Q,789 as 5. Either is fine.

Case L,M : Only two sub-categories and both even merged will remain less than 5 but that's the best we can have so it should be L,M,456 as 4.

Case S,T : Only 789 has less than 5 so it can go with either 123 or 456 (as both have same samples), but not both. So the answer should be either S,T,123 as 5 and S,T,456 as 8 or S,T,123 as 8 and S,T,456 as 5.

What happens if there is a third column with values and based on the logic we want them to be merged too - add up if its an integer, and concatenate if that's a string - based on whatever condition we use on these columns?

I have been trying to break the column category then work with samples to add up but so far no luck. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very tricky question especially with the structure of your data(because your grouper which is really the parts "A,B", "X,Y", etc. are not in a separate column. But I think you can do:

```
df.sort_values(by='Samples', inplace=True, ignore_index=True)
#grouper containing groupby keys ['A,B', 'X,Y', etc.)
g = df['Category'].str.extract("(.*),+")[0] 
#create a column to keep the category together
df['sample_category'] = list(zip(df['Samples'], df['Category']))
```

Then use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) to reduce the list by iteratively grabbing the next tuple if sample is less than 5:

```
df2 = df.groupby(g, as_index=False).agg(
{'sample_category': lambda s: 
 functools.reduce(lambda x, y: (x[0] + y[0], y[1]) if x[0] < 5 else (x, y), s)})
```

Then do some munging to modify the elements to a list type:

```
df2['sample_category'] = df2['sample_category'].apply(
lambda x: [x] if isinstance(x[0], int) else list(x))
```

Then explode, extract columns and finally drop the intermediate column 'sample_category'

```
df2 = df2.explode('sample_category', ignore_index=True)
df2['Sample'] = df2['sample_category'].str[0]
df2['Category'] = df2['sample_category'].str[1]
df2.drop('sample_category', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

print(df2):

```
   Sample Category
0      10  A,B,123
1       4  L,M,456
2       5  P,Q,789
3       8  S,T,123
4       5  S,T,456
5       9  X,Y,456
6      18  X,Y,123
```

Comment: functools.reduce tries to reduce a list based on the function we supply. Read the link I mentioned in the answer. Here for this data, we get a list of sample_category and we run through the list trying to reduce it. The logic in reducing is if we see a value less than 5, append it to existing one and continue. Because the samples are sorted, the reduce will stop at the value where a value > 5 is seen.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Can you please help me explain the part where you do functools.reduce transformation. In reality I have 4 categories like X,Y,Z,123 and when I am trying to tweak this to make it work for my case, it throws error. Also, if I have a third column which has lists as values and as I merged the sample by size, can I merge the elements in the list too using the same rules?

Comment: Now about your 'reality' : what do you mean you have 4 categories like X,Y,Z,123 do you have duplicate rows with X,Y,Z,1,2,3 and different sample values? You could groupby and sum before executing steps in my answer. I don't know about your third column how it looks like and what do you want to happen to that. So I can't comment on your third column.

Comment: I mean the hierarchal nature of the problem here is 3 fold. What I have is 4 fold. X,Y,Z,1123 and not X,Y,123. The merge still must happen on the last instance of the sequence. 

When I use your example it gives me:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'

Comment: It works for me. Can you show your data frame constructor like df = pd.Dataframe(…)?